How to achieve 'separated' cline?
How can I create a 'break' between the cline{5-6} such that there is a visible separation between the two columns? The reason is that the clines here are intended to show that the figure is summed from the figures below.

MWE (note: although not obvious from this example, I need to use longtable):
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}  %% sans serif base
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{siunitx} % For aligning numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables that span multiple pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{array} % For advanced table features
\usepackage{multirow}

% proper bold casing in siunitx
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}

% siunitx setup
\sisetup{
round-mode=places,
round-precision=0,
group-separator={,},
group-minimum-digits=4, % groups digits by thousands
input-ignore={,},
detect-all,
detect-weight=true,
detect-inline-weight=math,
tight-spacing=true,
table-number-alignment = right % Align numbers to the right
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Agency – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE TITLE}\\[0.1in]
Officer – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE NAME}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\fancyhead[C]{Annual Report – \textbf{ORGANISATION NAME}\\[0.1in]
\textit{Officer in Charge} : \textbf{OFFICER NAME}}


\begin{longtable}{
    @{}p{1cm}  % Column for 'Butiran' with fixed width
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}   % Column left-aligned
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.2cm}   % Column left-aligned
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}  % Column center-aligned
    S[table-format=11.0]
    S[table-format=11.0]
    S[table-format=6.0]
    S[table-format=6.0]@{}
}
\toprule
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Code}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Title}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Object}\\ \textbf{Code}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Estimate} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Estimate} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Positions} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Positions} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
\midrule
\\
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Code}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Title}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Object}\\ \textbf{Code}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Estimate} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Estimate} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Positions} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Positions} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
\midrule
\\
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\bfseries 180000 & \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}}{\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright \bfseries MONIES SENT ABROAD FOR PURPOSES OF AID AND REPARATION}}} & & 0 & \B 20000000000 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
\vspace{0\baselineskip} 
& & & 40000 & 0 & \B 20000000000 & &  \\* \\* \\ 

& 180100 & {\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright Monies Sent Abroad for Purposes of Aid and Reparation}}} & & 0 & \B 2000000 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
\vspace{0\baselineskip} 
& & & 40000 & 0 & \B 2000000 & &  \\* \\* \\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}



use booktabs  package \cmidrule (it works with longtable)

Like this:

You only need to split your \cline{5-6} into two clines to which you add options for its shortness on the right and left respectively.
For example, based on my answer on your previous question, an example how to do this is:
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}  %% sans serif base
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin=0.5in,vmargin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Agency – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE TITLE}\\[0.1in]
    Officer – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE NAME}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{tabularray} % For tables that span multiple pages
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx} % For prettier tables
% proper bold casing in siunitx
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}


\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}  
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{} 
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4,
         drop-zero-decimal,
         detect-weight=true,
         }
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none, 
    label=none, 
                ]{width=0.9\textwidth,      % if the table needs to be narrower than the width of the text
                  colspec = {@{} Q[l, font=\bfseries]
                                 Q[l, wd=11mm]
                                 X[l, cmd=\linespread{0.82}\relax]
                                 c
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=11.0}]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=11.0}]  
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=4.0}] 
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=4.0}]  @{}},
                hspan=minimal,
                row{1} = {guard, font=\bfseries, c, m},
                rowsep = 7pt,
                rowhead = 1,
                }
     \toprule
Code    &   \SetCell[c=2]{}    Title 
            &   &   {Object\\ Code}
                    &   {Estimate\\ 2023}
                        &   {Estimate\\ 2024}
                            &   {Estimate\\ 2023}
                                &   {Estimate\\ 2024}   \\ 
    \midrule
000000  &   \SetCell[c=2, r=2]{font=\bfseries}    MONIES SENT ABROAD FOR PURPOSES OF AID AND REPARATION
            &   & 0 & \B 20000000000 
                        &   &   &                       \\*
    \cmidrule[r=-0.4]{5-5}    % <---
    \cmidrule[l=-0.4]{6-6}    % <---
        &   &   & 40000 
                    & 0 & \B 20000000000 
                            &   &                       \\*
%
        &   180100 
            &      \SetCell[r=2]{}      Monies Sent Abroad for Purposes of Aid and Reparation
                &   & 0 & \B 2000000 
                            &   &                       \\*
    \cmidrule[r=-0.4]{5-5}    % <---
    \cmidrule[l=-0.4]{6-6}    % <---
%
        &   &   & 40000 
                    & 0 & \B 2000000 
                            &   &                       \\*
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


BTW, I wonder why you not accept any of answer to mentioned your previous question?

Upvoting because it does provide a suggestion, but is there a way to achieve this without changing the package used?
I really need longtable so that I can properly implement multi-page tables.

@Thev, in text I explain what to do (also without changing any package in your document), This works with your code too, but for shortening of \cline see its syntax used in longtable . It is bit different from syntax used tabularray but principle is the same. Its syntax is explained in the longtable package documentation.

@Thev, BTW: I think the only reason you need `longtable' is that you have (at least partially) learned how to use it and that you are not ready to invest new effort in learning to use a new package...
